Invertible Matrix for diagonalisation for solving differential equations
For the  following question I've gotten a matrix $P =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ that works for $P^{-1}AP=J$ but doesn't work for the final solution, I think because the final column doesn't have a zero as the matrix $P =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ does work, why is this the case?

$1.$
$\text{(a)}$ Suppose that $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix and that $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. If there is a non-zero vector $\mathbf{v}_3$ such that
$$
(A - \lambda I)\mathbf{v}_3 = \mathbf{v}_2,
$$
show that the set of vectors $\{\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2, \mathbf{v}_3\}$ is linearly independent.
If the vectors $\mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2$ and $\mathbf{v}_3$ are the columns of the matrix $P$, explain why $P^{-1}AP = J$ where $J$ is a Jordan matrix that you should find.

$\text{(b)}$ Let $A$ be the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Use part $\text{(a)}$ to find an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J$ where $J$ is a Jordan matrix.

$\text{(c)}$ Hence solve the system of differential equations
$$
\begin{align}
f'(t) &= -3f(t) + g(t) + h(t), \\
g'(t) &= -2g(t), \\
h'(t) &= -f(t) + g(t) - h(t),
\end{align}
$$
when $f(0) = 2, \, g(0) = 2$ and $h(0) = 1$.

Edit: My solution paper has $f(t)=(2+2t)e^{-2t}$ but I got $f(t)=(1+t)e^{-2t}$  and note sure why the discrepancy - see the excerpt below:

$\text{(c)}$ The given system of differential equations is $\mathbf{f}' = A\mathbf{f}$ where
$$
\mathbf{f} = \begin{pmatrix}
f(t) \\
g(t) \\
h(t)
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \quad A = \begin{pmatrix}
-3 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the matrix in part $\text{(b)}$. Set $\mathbf{f} = P\mathbf{x}$ where
$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
x(t) \\
y(t) \\
z(t)
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{so that we have} \quad (P\mathbf{x})' = A(P\mathbf{x}) \implies \mathbf{x}' = P^{-1}AP\mathbf{x} = J\mathbf{x}
$$
giving us the differential equations
$$
x'(t) = -2x(t), \quad y'(t) = -2y(t) + z(t) \quad \text{and} \quad z'(t) = -2z(t)
$$
which have general solutions given by
$$
x(t) = Ae^{-2t}, \quad y(t) = (Ct + B)e^{-2t} \quad \text{and} \quad z(t) = Ce^{-2t},
$$
for some arbitrary constants $A$, $B$ and $C$. The solution of $\mathbf{f}' = A\mathbf{f}$ is then given by
$$
\mathbf{f} = P\mathbf{x} = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
Ae^{-2t} \\
(Ct + B)e^{-2t} \\
Ce^{-2t}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
A + B + Ct \\
A + C \\
Ct + B
\end{pmatrix} e^{-2t}.
$$
Now, using the initial conditions $f(0) = 2$, $g(0) = 2$, and $h(0) = 1$ we get the equations
$$
2 = A + B, \quad A + C = 2 \quad \text{and} \quad B = 1,
$$
which clearly give us $A = 1$, $B = 1$, and $C = 0$ so that
$$
f(t) = (2t + 2)e^{-2t}, \quad g(t) = 2e^{-2t} \quad \text{and} \quad h(t) = (t + 1)e^{-2t}, \\
[\ldots]
$$


Used $|A-\lambda I| =0$ and solved to find eigenvalues and subsequently eigenvectors, then set columns of P equal to eigenvectors.

@Moo Not sure what happened to your answer?

I noticed that $(1,1,1)^T$ works for the final eigenvector so just stuck with that. Of course others e.g. $(-1,0,0)^T$ or $(0,1,0)^T$ also work.

We have the matrix
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
 -3 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
We find three repeated eigenvalues from $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, as $\lambda_{1,2,3} = -2$.
We find eigenvectors using $[A - \lambda I] = [A +2I]v_i = 0$ using the RREF
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}v_i = \begin{pmatrix}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can find two linearly independent eigenvectors from this as
$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}, ~~~~ v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\
 0 \\
 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
However, we cannot find a third independent eigenvector because we have a deficient matrix, and the hint gives us an approach to try for a third, generalized eigenvector.
We have $[A + 2I]v_3 = v_2$ and using RREF
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This gives $a = -1 + b + c$, so we can choose $b = c = 0$, giving
$$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
 -1 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can now write
$$P = \left(v_1 | v_2 | v_3 \right) = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 1 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can write $J = P^{-1} A P$ and then verify $A = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1}$.
Update The eigenvectors are not unique. We could have chosen
$$v_3 = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
This leads to
$$J = P^{-1} \cdot A \cdot P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 -2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
We can verify $A = P \cdot J \cdot P^{-1}$. In other words, your other solution is okay too.
We can then find the solution using either $P$ (I verified the result with both) to arrive at
$$X(t) = P \cdot e^{Jt} \cdot P^{-1} \cdot X(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
 f(t) \\
 g(t) \\
 h(t) \\
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 e^{-2 t} (t+2) \\
 2 e^{-2 t} \\
 e^{-2 t} (t+1) \\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Update 2: I also used $P =\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and got the same result.
Update 3: It is easy to see where the solution went wrong as they made a simple algebra error. They show
$$\begin{align} A + B &= 2 \\ A + C &= 2 \\ B&=1 \end{align}$$
Solving this results in $A = B = C = 1$, and not $C = 0$.
Substituting this back in to their work gives the same result as mine.

Isn't $\lambda =-2$

why is 4th column of RREF $(-1,0,0)^T$?

I understand that multiple invertible matrices $P$ exist but you didn't answer why my first matrix $P$ doesn't lead to the correct  answer for c  unlike my 2nd invertible matrix $P$

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Yes, but when I try using my matrix $P$ in part C to solve the differential equations I get a different answer to the solution I have that used the 2nd $P$ Matrix. Why is that if both diagonalise $A$?

I got the same but my solution paper has  $f(t) =(2+2t)e^{-2t}$

See latest edit to the question

Looks like they made an algebra or transcription error, see this result using Wolfram Alpha. Note, you can also test my result by plugging it back in and checking that the LHS = RHS.
